# Show that $x_{n+2} − x_{n+1} = o(x_{n+1} − x_n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, numerical-methods

Let a sequence $x_n$ be defined inductively by $x_{n+1} = F(x_n)$ with $F$ say $C^1$. Suppose that $x_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and $F'(x) = 0$. Show that
$x_{n+2} − x_{n+1} = o(x_{n+1} − x_n)$

I know that I should be using the mean value theorem but I am having a trouble finding a sequence $\epsilon_n$ such that $F(x_{n+1}) - F(x_n) \leq \epsilon_n |x_{n+1} - x_n|$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence you're looking for is $f^\prime(\xi_n)$ with $\xi_n \in (x_{n+1},x_n)$ which is converging to zero according to your hypothesis.

Using the Mean Value Theorem you get the existence of $\xi_n$ with  $$F(x_{n+1})-F(x_n)=F^\prime(\xi_n) (x_{n+1}-x_n)$$